# Delete empty value element in array

Tags: php

```
Array
    (
      [0] => 0   //value is int 0 which isn;t empty value
      [1] =>     //this is empty value
      [2] =>     //this is empty value
    )
```

I would like to make the above array to be as the following, Can anyone help me?

Many thanks

```
Array
    (
      [0] => 0
    )
```

Comment: What are those empty values? Are they false, NULL, empty strings or something else? What about the 0? Is it the integer 0, or the string "0"? Use `var_dump()` on your array to determine the types of the values.

Answer (score 20):

You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove empty value (null, false,'',0):

```
array_filter($array);
```

If you don't want to remove `0` from your array, see @Sabari's answer:

```
array_filter($array,'strlen');
```

Comment: Didn't know that the second argument is optional, that's neat.

Comment: @Zulkhaery Basrul, array_filter would think value 0 is empty value, so final result is an empty array which isn't what i want

Comment: As of PHP 8.1, strlen will now emit a deprecated error "strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated"

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

To Remove NULL values only:

```
$new_array_without_nulls = array_filter($array_with_nulls, 'strlen');
```

To Remove False Values:

```
$new_array_without_nulls = array_filter($array_with_nulls);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: As of PHP 8.1, strlen will now emit a deprecated error "strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated"

Comment: Also... the `strlen` callback would also remove empty string and `false` values (in addition to `null`)

Answer (score 1):

```
array_filter($array, function($var) {
    //because you didn't define what is the empty value, I leave it to you
    return !is_empty($var);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a typical case for [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter). You first need to define a function that returns `TRUE` if the value should be preserved and `FALSE` if it should be removed:

```
function preserve($value)
{
    if ($value === 0) return TRUE;

    return FALSE;
}

$array = array_filter($array, 'preserve');
```

You then specify in the callback function (here `preserve`) what is empty and what not. You have not written in your question specifically, so you need to do it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

quick way to find numbers also Zero (0)

```
    var_dump(  
            array_filter( array('0',0,1,2,3,'text') , 'is_numeric'  )
        );
/* 
print :
array (size=5)
  0 => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => int 0
  2 => int 1
  3 => int 2
  4 => int 3

*/
```