# How to get values separated with comma from database using PHP

Tags: php, database, php-5.3, php-5.2

I have four files named comma separated in one field in database like this `file1`,`file2`,`file3`,`file4`. It may change depending on files uploading. User can upload maximum 4 files, minimum one file. But I was not able to get it. I used explode but it's taking too long.

I am using this code:

```
      $imagefiles = $row["imagefiles"];


      $cutjobs = explode(",", $imagefiles);
      $cutjobs1 = count($cutjobs);

      $image1 = $cutjobs[0];
      $image2 = $cutjobs[1];
      $image3 = $cutjobs[2];
      $image4 = $cutjobs[3];

      if (empty($image1)) {
        $imagefiles1 = "";
      } else {
        $imagefiles1 = 'http://projects.santabantathegreat.com/glassicam/uploads/'.$registerid.
        "/".$viewjobsid.
        "/".$image1;
      }

      if (empty($image2)) {
        $imagefiles2 = "";
      } else {
        $imagefiles2 = 'http://projects.santabantathegreat.com/glassicam/uploads/'.$registerid.
        "/".$viewjobsid.
        "/".$image2;
      }
      if (empty($image3)) {
        $imagefiles3 = "";
      } else {
        $imagefiles3 = 'http://projects.santabantathegreat.com/glassicam/uploads/'.$registerid.
        "/".$viewjobsid.
        "/".$image3;
      }
      if (empty($image4)) {
        $imagefiles4 = "";
      } else {
        $imagefiles4 = 'http://projects.santabantathegreat.com/glassicam/uploads/'.$registerid.
        "/".$viewjobsid.
        "/".$image4;
      }
    }

    $data[] = array( 'imagearray' => array($imagefiles, $imagefiles1, $imagefiles2, $imagefiles3));


  }
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

I am getting output like this :

```
[{"imagearray":["http:\/\/projects.santabantathegreat.com\/glassicam\/uploads\/60\/30\/file1.jpg","http:\/\/projects.santabantathegreat.com\/glassicam\/uploads\/60\/30\/file2.jpg",""]}]
```

If you see this imageArray last one is getting ""  that means some in `file1`, `file2`, `file3`, `file4` one name is missing so I want to show if any filename is not there means I don't want to show null values with ""

i have a field with file1,file2,file3,file4 so times we will have file1,file3 then remaining will not there so i want to count file name separated with commas and if file1 is there is should print that if file3 is there not then it shouldn't show with ""

Comment: Why didn't you use explode ?

Comment: i am new in php is there is any way to use than explode

Comment: Although it may or may not be within your control, this is a poor database design. Whenever you combine multiple items in a single database column you will have problems splitting it.  A better design would be to have table that contains the file names and joins back to the main table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have used `split()`, but its [deprecated in PHP 5.3.0](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php). So, instead you are left with:

- `explode()` which is substantially faster because it doesn't split based on a regular expression, so the string doesn't have to be analyzed by the regex parser.

or

- `preg_split()` which is faster and uses PCRE regular expressions for regex splits.

With `preg_split()` you could do:

```
<?php
   $encoded_data = json_encode($data); 
   $images = preg_split('/,/', $encoded_data->imagearray);
?>
```

I would say that `explode()` is more appropriate for this.

```
<?php
   $encoded_data = json_encode($data); 
   $images = explode(',', $encoded_data->imagearray);
   print_r($images);
?>
```

***Resources:*** [What is the difference between split() and explode()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640990/what-is-the-difference-between-split-and-explode)

---

You shouldn't have empty values in your array in the first place. But if you still have any empty values you could use `preg_split()` something like [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64570/explode-that-doesnt-return-empty-strings).

Similarly you can use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to handle removal of values `(null, false,'',0)`:

```
print_r(array_filter($images));
```

There are so many answers here in this forum that do exactly what you are asking: [Remove empty array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements), [Delete empty value element in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062871/delete-empty-value-element-in-array).

Comment: did you understand my question in image array  you have $imagefiles,$imagefiles1,$imagefiles2,$imagefiles3 if any one is not there means it showing null or ""

Comment: You shouldn't insert null values in the first place.

Comment: may be you didn't understand my question i have a field with file1,file2,file3,file4 so times we will have file1,file3 then remaining will not there so i want to count file name separated with commas  and if file1 is there is should print that if file3 is there not then it shouldn't show with ""

Comment: no you can see how am i am getting http://projects.santabantathegreat.com/glassicam/sendjobs.php?registeredid=60

Comment: where i should use that instead of array i should use array_filter